# Cannot start storm application. Error on initialization of server mk-worker

Tags: java, apache, apache-zookeeper, apache-storm, apache-storm-topology

I am having error continuously for storm application on cluster. I have two same application with exactly same configuration except for the name, specific variables. One is working and one not. Here is the log:

I am running storm app on ubuntu vms, with 2 zookeeper servers, 2 nimbus seeds configured in storm.yaml file. storm.local.dir is /data/storm-local.

```
2017-10-27 14:55:50.243 o.a.s.d.worker main [ERROR] Error on initialization of server mk-worker
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.nio.file.FileSystems.getDefault(FileSystems.java:176) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
        at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:84) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
        at org.apache.storm.util$is_absolute_path_QMARK_.invoke(util.clj:68) ~[storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
        at org.apache.storm.config$absolute_storm_local_dir.invoke(config.clj:94) ~[storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
        at org.apache.storm.config$worker_root.invoke(config.clj:290) ~[storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
        at org.apache.storm.config$worker_root.invoke(config.clj:292) ~[storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
        at org.apache.storm.config$worker_pids_root.invoke(config.clj:296) ~[storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
        at org.apache.storm.config$worker_pid_path.invoke(config.clj:304) ~[storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.worker$fn__5471$exec_fn__1371__auto____5472.invoke(worker.clj:594) ~[storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:178) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:630) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.worker$fn__5471$mk_worker__5562.doInvoke(worker.clj:585) [storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:512) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.worker$_main.invoke(worker.clj:769) [storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:165) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.worker.main(Unknown Source) [storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
        at java.nio.file.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystemHolder.defaultFileSystem(FileSystems.java:96) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
        at java.nio.file.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystemHolder.<clinit>(FileSystems.java:90) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
        ... 18 more
Caused by: sun.nio.fs.UnixException: No such file or directory
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixNativeDispatcher.getcwd(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystem.<init>(UnixFileSystem.java:67) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystem.<init>(LinuxFileSystem.java:39) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystemProvider.newFileSystem(LinuxFileSystemProvider.java:46) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystemProvider.newFileSystem(LinuxFileSystemProvider.java:39) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.<init>(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:56) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystemProvider.<init>(LinuxFileSystemProvider.java:41) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.nio.fs.DefaultFileSystemProvider.createProvider(DefaultFileSystemProvider.java:48) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.nio.fs.DefaultFileSystemProvider.create(DefaultFileSystemProvider.java:63) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
        at java.nio.file.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystemHolder.getDefaultProvider(FileSystems.java:108) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
        at java.nio.file.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystemHolder.access$000(FileSystems.java:89) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
        at java.nio.file.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystemHolder$1.run(FileSystems.java:98) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
        at java.nio.file.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystemHolder$1.run(FileSystems.java:96) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
        at java.nio.file.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystemHolder.defaultFileSystem(FileSystems.java:96) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
        at java.nio.file.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystemHolder.<clinit>(FileSystems.java:90) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
        ... 18 more
2017-10-27 14:55:52.615 o.a.s.util main [ERROR] Halting process: ("Error on initialization")
java.lang.RuntimeException: ("Error on initialization")
        at org.apache.storm.util$exit_process_BANG_.doInvoke(util.clj:341) [storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:423) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.worker$fn__5471$mk_worker__5562.doInvoke(worker.clj:585) [storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:512) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.worker$_main.invoke(worker.clj:769) [storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:165) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.worker.main(Unknown Source) [storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
2017-10-27 14:59:28.579 STDERR Thread-2 [INFO] Error occurred during initialization of VM
2017-10-27 14:59:30.618 STDERR Thread-2 [INFO] java.lang.Error: Properties init: Could not determine current working directory.
2017-10-27 14:59:30.619 STDERR Thread-2 [INFO]  at java.lang.System.initProperties(Native Method)
2017-10-27 14:59:30.619 STDERR Thread-2 [INFO]  at java.lang.System.initializeSystemClass(System.java:1166)
2017-10-27 14:59:30.630 STDERR Thread-2 [INFO]
2017-10-27 15:02:04.098 STDERR Thread-2 [INFO] Error occurred during initialization of VM
2017-10-27 15:02:04.797 STDERR Thread-2 [INFO] java.lang.Error: Properties init: Could not determine current working directory.
2017-10-27 15:02:04.809 STDERR Thread-2 [INFO]  at java.lang.System.initProperties(Native Method)
2017-10-27 15:02:04.810 STDERR Thread-2 [INFO]  at java.lang.System.initializeSystemClass(System.java:1166)
2017-10-27 15:02:04.811 STDERR Thread-2 [INFO]
2017-10-27 15:07:33.882 STDERR Thread-2 [INFO] Error occurred during initialization of VM
2017-10-27 15:07:34.280 STDERR Thread-2 [INFO] java.lang.Error: Properties init: Could not determine current working directory.
```

I did the following to solve but failed:

- Restarted couple of times. No luck. Increased memory.
- Reduce number of workers to 2 (total 12 are available). Removed all other apps and tried to run only one app. still failing.
- made sure /data/storm-local directory has permission to read/write files.